# Definition of binary operation on a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, functions

About the definition of binary operation on a set, in my notes it says a binary operation on S  is a map $*:S\times S\to S$, it does not have to be a function, it is a mapping. But in the textbook, it says while defining a binary operation on a set $S$, we must be sure that exactly one element is assigned to each possible ordered pair of elements. Doesn't that mean it is a function? I am confused here, does a binary operation have to be a function? Thanks

Comment: Usually, map (mapping) and function mean exactly the same. How do they differ in your notes?

Comment: in my notes, it explicitly says that it is just a map, not a function. What i understand from this sentence is, more than one element can be assigned to a pair

Comment: We can’t answer the question until we know exactly how the terms *mapping* and *function* have been defined for you. In most contexts either they mean exactly the same thing, or mappings are functions with some additional property; in neither case is it possible to have a mapping that is not a function.

Comment: You still haven't told us why you think a mapping and a function are different things.

Comment: i am not sure, but i think that in a mapping, more than one element can be assigned to a pair according to this definition. IS that wrong?

Comment: That’s wrong by any definition of *mapping* that I’ve ever encountered.

Comment: Agreed, all definitions of map I've encountered are functions. Perhaps you are confusing "map" with "relation." Relations can have zero or more values related to them.

Comment: So, you say that a binary operation is a well defined function?

Comment: Yes, it is a function, which implicitly means well-defined.

Comment: ok then, thanks

Comment: If you are reading old mathematical literature (> 50 years) then you may well encounter uses of map/function that denote what we now mean by multivalued map/functions. This is rare in modern texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A binary operation on $S$ **is** a function $S\times S\to S$. You are correct.